# Problema com Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, injeção-de-dependência

Estou com um problemas ao qual não consegui identificar o que está provocando.
Ao tentar entrar na View de registro, ocorre um "internal Server Error" e aparece a mensagem abaixo.

Estou utilizando ASP.NET Core 2.1.1

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'AgendaWeb.Data.ApplicationDbContext' from singleton 'AgendaWeb.Domain.IRepository`1[AgendaWeb.Domain.Users.User]'.

[AgendaWeb.Domain.Users.User]

```
using AgendaWeb.Domain.Adresses;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace AgendaWeb.Domain.Users
{
    public class User : Entity
    {       
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public string Cpf { get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string Phone { get; private set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; private set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; private set; }
    public string ProfileType { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }

    public User()
    {

    }     

    public User(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address)
    {
        ValidateValues(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);
        SetProperties(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);

    }

    public void Update(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address)
    {
        ValidateValues(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);
        SetProperties(userName, fullName, cpf, email, phone, cellPhone, photoUrl, password, registrationDate, dateOfBirth, profileType, address);

    }

    private void SetProperties(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        FullName = fullName;
        Cpf = cpf;
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
        CellPhone = cellPhone;
        PhotoUrl = photoUrl;
        Password = password;
        RegistrationDate = registrationDate;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        ProfileType = profileType;
        Address = address;
    }

    private static void ValidateValues(string userName, string fullName, string cpf, string email, string phone, string cellPhone, string photoUrl, string password, DateTime registrationDate, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string profileType, Address address)
    {
        DomainException.When(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName), "O campo nome é obrigatório!");
        DomainException.When(address == null, "O campo endereço é obrigatório!");
    }
}
}
```

AgendaWeb.Domain.IRepository

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace AgendaWeb.Domain
{
    public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    {
        TEntity GetById(int id);

        void Save(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: cade seu context, e seu controller ?

Comment: posta a sua classe startup por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua classe Startup, a interface IRepository deve estar definida como Singleton, altere para Scoped ou Transient.

Isso ocorre pois a classe ApplicationDbContext está como scoped, ou seja, uma instância é criada por requisição, e IRepository está como singleton, ou seja, uma instância para toda a aplicação, e essa divergência é o que está causando o problema.